# TwilioQuest - -Help, with my code. Python class called Citizen

Tags: python

What am I missing in my code? I've tried different variations of this code, maybe five. I've run the code and I get the statement to execute, but there is still something missing. The name doesn't print along with it. Attached is a screenshot of the parameters that were given.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QjRq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INdkZ.png)

```
class Citizen:
  """
  this class is to describe a citizen of the City of Python
  """   
def __init__(self, first_name, last_name): 
    self.first_name = Rey
    self.last_name = Rizo
def full_name(x):
    x = self.first_name + self.last_name
def greeting(greet):
    full_name = raw_input(full_name)
    return greet + x
print("For the glory of Python!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Citizen:
    "this class is to describe a citizen of the City of Python"   
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name): 
        self.first_name = first_name #this is an instance variable
        self.last_name = last_name
    def full_name(self):    #This is an instance method
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name  #This took the 2 instance variables and put them together
    greeting = "For the glory of Python!"
```

This is what worked for me.

Comment: Thank you. I see what I was missing. '''return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name'''. I rewrote the code a few times but always missed this part. Thank you, again.

Answer (score 0):

```py
class Citizen:
    """
    this class is to describe a citizen of the City of Python
    """   
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name): 
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
    def full_name():
        return self.first_name + self.last_name

    def greeting(greet):
        return greet + self.full_name()
```

When you initiate a new citizen, use:

```py
citizen = Citizen(“first_name”, “last_name”)
```

To print the name:

```py
print(citizen.full_name)
```

To greet:

```
print(citizen.greeting(“Hello”))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
class Citizen:
    """a citizen of the City of Python"""

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name


    def full_name(self):
        return (f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}')

    greeting = 'For the glory of Python!'
```

This worked for me.